# Woocommerce set shipping tax to zero

Tags: php, woocommerce

i try to set the woocommerce shippingcost to zero as soon as the customers is adding an specific product to the card (see bellow) which works fine. the problem is that the shipping tax keeping are not set to zero as were the shippingcosts still there. is there any way to additional set the tax also to zero, something like this ? .. $rate->tax = 0;

Thank you.

```
function adjust_shipping_rate( $rates ){
  global $woocommerce;
  global  $free_product_id;


  $cart_counter = 0;
   
     
  foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
      $cart_counter += 1;
  }



  $product_ids = array_merge(
    wp_list_pluck(WC()->cart->get_cart_contents(), 'variation_id'),
    wp_list_pluck(WC()->cart->get_cart_contents(), 'product_id')
  );
   
  
  if ( $cart_counter > 1  && in_array($free_product_id, $product_ids)){

          foreach ($rates as $rate) {
              
              $rate->cost = 0;
          }

  }
    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'adjust_shipping_rate', 50, 1 );
```